# django image not loading in many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django

I have one model for the date and another model for images and a third many-to-many model that connects images to dates but in the template, I made a for loop but no image is showing up

and in the developer console, I see

```
<img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="" alt="">
```

my models.py

```
class MyDate(models.Model):
    english_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False)
    hebrew_date = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self ):
        return reverse('date_detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.hebrew_date

# images
class Images(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(unique=False,upload_to='images/')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("image_detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

#connect days and images together
class DayImage(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey('luach.MyDate',related_name='day',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ManyToManyField('luach.images',related_name='images')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pk
```

my views.py

```
def my_date_detail(request,pk):
    mydate = MyDate.objects.get(pk=pk)
    dayimage = DayImage.objects.filter(date=mydate)

    context = {'mydate':mydate,'dayimage':dayimage}
    return render(request, 'luach/mydate_detail.html',context)
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('date/<int:pk>',views.MyDateDetailView.as_view(),name='date_detail'),
    path('date/<int:pk>/add_image/',views.create_day_image_view,name='add_image')
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and I do have a media URL setup

```
 MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

my mydate_detail.html

```
  <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Images</h2>
        {% for p in dayimage %}
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
                <div class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                    <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="{{ p.image.url }}" alt="hi">   
                </div>
            </div>
        {% empty %}
            <h3>There is no images linked to this day</h3>
        {% endfor %}
        <a class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm" href="{% url 'add_image' pk=mydate.pk %}">add image</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have field "image" on your DayImage model, so you should iterate over "images"

```
{% for p in dayimage %}
    {% for im in p.images.all %}
          <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="{{ im.image.url }}" alt="hi">   
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: this must be working. please share if u saw any error?

Comment: I added another for loop and an empty and I received the empty message the number of times I have an image in the db

Comment: @Moskovitz show your current version of template code

Comment: {% for p in dayimage %}
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
                {% for image in p.images.all %}    
                <div class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
                        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="{{ p.image.url }}" alt="hi">   
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% empty %}
            <h3>There is no images linked to this day</h3>
        {% endfor %}

Comment: @Moskovitz well, two thigs. 1. This code still tries to access p.image (which does not exist) instead of image.image. 2. Your empty block is a part of the first loop, so it is empty when your view returns empty queryset in "dayimage". Check your filter condition.

Answer (score 0):

> First thing in the function 'get_absolute_url', in kwargs={'pk':self.pk}), you have to delete 'self.' before 'pk', It's already defined as self_function so it will return a self_primary_key for the image. It will be apear like :

```
 def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("image_detail",kwargs={'pk':pk})
```

> Now, you sould to read all the image pk's in your database, not only the pk for one image, because you will have a lot of images, so if you return only one pk, the browser will show you the first image only, so use a for loop, and your code should apear like :

```
...           
 <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
    {% for image in p.images.all %}    
      <div class="d-block mb-4 h-100">
             <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="{{ p.image.url }}" alt="hi">   
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
 </div>
...
```

Also in the class 'DayImage' you have to delete the 'self.' before the 'pk' in the return.

Comment: thanks, I tried it but I'm not getting the images just `<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6"></div><div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6"></div>`